# Array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to store an array of objects inside mongodb with mongoose and node, with simple validation and getting a really hard time with it

I'm defining a Schema and a custom validation function like so:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const fieldsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 250,
  },
  list: {
    type: Array,
    primaryText: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 250,
    },
    secondaryText: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 250,
    },
    listType: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["listOne", "listTwo"],
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 250,
    },
    items: {
      required: isListTypeTwo,
      type: Array,
      itemTitle: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 250,
      },
      itemContent: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 250,
      },
    },
  },
});

function isListTypeTwo() {
  if (this.listType === "listTwo") return true;
  return false;
}

const Field = new mongoose.model("Field", fieldsSchema);

exports.fieldsSchema = fieldsSchema;
exports.Field = Field;
```

And then I'm creating a Post Route like so:

```
const { Field } = require("../models/field");

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  let field = new Field({
    title: req.body.title,
    list: req.body.list,
  });
  field = await field.save();
  res.send(field);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I pass my JSON data with postman like so:

```
{
    "title": "title",
    "list": [
        {
            "primaryText": "primaryText",
            "secondaryText": "secondaryText",
            "listType": "listOne"
        },
        {
            "primaryText": "primaryText",
            "secondaryText": "secondaryText",
            "listType": "listTwo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, here some questions I can't solve and ask for your help:

1. How can I pass a properly defined structure of an array to my route, so to say instead of:
   `list: req.body.list`, something more detail(but without accessing each object manually, of course, like ~[0], ~[1], etc)?
2. Why does my validation not working?
3. Perhaps I should pass a JSON in some other way/structure?

Comment: What is the error with your schema validation?

Comment: There's no error tbh, it just goes and eats whatever I feed it within the `req.body.list`

Comment: Even if I simply remove the function reference there(validation) and simply add `true`, it still goes through without any error messages. I think it's due the fact how the `req.body.list` is passed, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware to correctly parse JSON.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express(); // no need to call Router()

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  // your stuff...
});
```

> How can I pass a properly defined structure of an array to my route, so to say instead of: list: req.body.list, something more detail(but without accessing each object manually, of course, like ~[0], ~[1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), etc)?

Not sure if I understand correctly, but maybe you only need a loop to save your fields?

```
  const promises = req.body.list.map(async (item) => { // map loop which will return array of promises
    const field = new Field({
      title: req.body.title,
      item,
    });
    return field.save(); // returning the promise
  });

  res.send(Promise.all(promises));
```

Also, add try/catch block to catch and log any possible error on your mongoose schema:

```
try {
  const field = new Field({
    title: req.body.title,
    item,
  });
  field.save();
  // success
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```